# Apache Ignite and Cassandra - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, cassandra, ignite

I wish to evaluate the performance gain of using Apache Ignite together with Apache Cassandra. I've built Ignite from source, the default configuration boots fine. Starting from the [example in the documentation](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/examples), I was then trying to set up a basic cluster, but I keep getting **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** on the classes used, for example **org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.datasource.DataSource**.

I've searched for the class files in the provided jars, ad set ambient variables accordingly (both CLASSPATH and USER_LIBS). Still, Ignite cannot find them. I am using ignite 1.7 and Oracle JDK 1.8.

Any suggestion wuold be really appreciated. Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to copy the **ignite-cassandra** folder into the **libs** folder as suggested in the README file. Tried with and without setting the IGNITE_HOME environment variable, both the bin and src distributions, still the required class cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was causing the issue. The [example provided](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/examples) in the Ignite documentation page has a subtle difference in the package structure of several classes, for example:

- `org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.datasource.DataSource` (the class in the ignite-cassandra.jar)
- `org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.utils.datasource.DataSource` (the class in the example)

The same applies also for other classes in the example. I do not know if this is due to a refactoring performed on the code which did not propagate through the examples, or simply I used a different version of the documentation in contrast with the one I was running.

Answer (score 0):

Copying `ignite-cassandra` folder into the `libs` must help. Note that it has to be done prior to node start. Also try to unset `CLASSPATH` and `USER_LIBS` variables if they are still modified and let `ignite.sh` script to create classpath. As long as your `libs` folder structure is correct, it should be done automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I wrote in the answer, it was mismatch with the package structure of the classes.